# Anylogic new branch throwing "cannot be resolved to a variable" error

Tags: java, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'm building an Anylogic model. I've built these models off and on for a few years, and I've never seen the program display this behavior.

Until this morning, it ran beautifully. I've made a single change in a single agent type—I've added an extra branch in the state space (with appropriate transitions into and out of it).

Anylogic now won't compile, telling me instead, `<branch name> cannot be resolved to a variable`. When I click on the java code to find the error, the line of code is:

`enterState(<branch name>, true);`

I've tried renaming the branch, tried copying and pasting from a different branch that had worked elsewhere in the state space. None of these work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, annoyingly this is more a bug report. Quitting and restarting fixed it.